# How to loop through group of check boxes that have same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have dynamic table that has table cell with checkbox field. This fields are populated from DB so my table is dynamic. I would like to loop through checkboxes based on their class name. In that loop I want to check value for each check box. For example if value is equal 1 I want checkbox to be checked, if not unchecked. Alo I'm not sure if possible but I would like to set unique ID for each of these check boxes. Since my table is dynamic my fields need to have unique ID's. Here is example of my code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Time Slots</th>
            <th>Block</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>~(SLOT_LABEL)</td>
            <td>
                <span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="CF-[Events]" class="block" id="block_"+Value that will make this ID unique. value="~(SLOT_ID)"/>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also in current language that I work with to read values from DB I have to use NAME tag. If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector to retrieve elements by both their `name` and `value`. Try this:

```
$('input[name="CF-[Events]"][value="1"]').prop("checked", true);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/q7vyn82e/)

Comment: Can I use class name instead of NAME tag to iterate?

Comment: You could, `$('input.block[value="1"]').prop("checked", true);` would work too.

Comment: Can I do this with if/else statement? Instead of doing this in one single statement?

Comment: You could, although it would be rather redundant and slower.

Comment: Can you provide an example please? I tried with $(this).val() but did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a jQuery solution, it is also possible to fetch these elements with the `querySelector`:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.block");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I would like to use CLASS name instead of NAME Tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in jquery by each loop

```
$('.ClassName').each(function(i, o) {
    // o is object in your case checkbox    
    // i is index
    // your code
});
```

Comment: How I would do checked and unchecked boxes based on the value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='CF-[Events]']").each(function() {
   if($(this).val() === "1")
   {
       $(this).prop("checked", true);
   }
});
```

Comment: Can I use class name instead of NAME tag?

Comment: See Rory's answer :)

Comment: When I tried to use your example with $(this).prop("checked", true); that did not work, if I used $('input.block[value="1"]').prop("checked", true); then works. Do you know maybe why? I'm asking because I would like to set if/else statement.

Comment: try `$(this).val() === 1` instead of "1"